# Student visa for an exchange program combined with tourism in Canada?

Tags: canada, student-visa

I'm planning to study in Canada as an exchange student for the Spring semester (January-April). It is okay to study in travel visa which allows me to stay at Canada for 6 months.

But my plan is study+travel so I'm planning to travel Canada after the study (May-July). As it takes longer than 6 months, I need a visa. Could I get a student visa?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

According to your plan, you'll enter Canada for an exchange program, and do not require a visa but can remain in Canada for up to a 6-month period. This suggests that you are a visa-free national and, were you to apply for a study visa for a short exchange program, you might be advised that you don't require one, as the exchange is for only 4 months.

Rather, once you are in Canada, consider applying for an extension, and doing so before the end of your authorized stay.

**[Extend your stay in Canada as a visitor](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp)**

> You should apply 30 days before your status expires to:
>
> - extend your visitor, student or work status,
> - change your permit type (for example, from a study permit to a work permit) or
> - change your permit condition(s) (for example, if you are studying and you want to change schools, or if you are working and you want to change jobs).
>
> Find out [how to extend your stay as a visitor](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend/visa.asp).